# JavaScript Inside AJAX to Request More AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I built a rudimentary page navigation system with *jQuery*. You click the next button, it retrieves the next page via *AJAX*; click the previous, it goes to the one before it, etc. The *AJAX* request is done via the *jQuery* `$('#dom').html().load()` method.

Inside one of the pages pulled is an a href link with an onclick which goes to a custom function (`loadPage()` -- the same function I'm using for the parent page navigation). As you can guess, the `onclick` event used inside the *AJAX* page does not work -- it's trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

Is there a simple way to make this work?  Perhaps some other *jQuery AJAX* method like *GET*? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe your loadPage() script is just available on your parent page...

try putting it on every page you request..

Comment: That's actually precisely what I was hoping to avoid. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are embedding JavaScript into your html. Don't do that. Put your JavaScript into an external file and include it with a script tag, just like you do with jQuery.

Comment: We all have our moments - sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes. Happy coding!